# While using passport-github, profile.emails is null despite user:email scope

Tags: passport.js, github-oauth

I'm trying to get the private email of github user via **passport-github**.
So this is my code with `scope: "user:email"`:

```
   import passport from "passport";    
    import GithubStrategy from "passport-github";
    
    passport.use(
      new GithubStrategy(
        {
          clientID: process.env.GH_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GH_CLIENT_SECRET,
          callbackURL: `http://localhost:4000${routes.ghLoginCallback}`,
          scope: "user:email",
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
          console.log(profile.emails);
        }
      )
    );
```

And now I get `undefined` from `profile.emails`.
I do get my `profile` correctly, but with `email:null` also.
Are there any possible problems that I'm missing?

Comment: Checkout this thread to see if it helps. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/issues/15
If there are issues you could potentially use `passport-github2` is actively maintained and has an example of how to get email data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah as @jasonandmonte mentioned, `passport-github2` worked for me! Thanks a lot.
However, some people are saying that only `passport-github` works for them (checkout the thread that @jasonandmonte mentioned), so anyone who are in same issue in future can try both one. (Structure is almost the same.)